# Angular 4 multiple router outlets one component for interaction

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'd like to create a router outlet in my root component to display a "control strip" like interaction bar, this control strip interactions with the current component at the deepest level activated.

Schematic visual representation of desired outcome:
[image: schematic visual representation of desired outcome]

The green square is the deepest child route, this is where my focus on the page lies. There are certain actions that can be performed within the green square. The green square should also decide what the pink online must contain.

How can I approach this issue the best possible way? (Keeping in mind there is a form of interaction between the segments)

```
@Component({
    selector: 'componentname',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/componentname.component.html'
})
export class ComponentNameComponent {
    constructor(){ }
}
```

*Possible fallback: I thought of other ways to approach this issue, one is to wrap the control strip content in a div which I can move to the purple div.*

Comment: You've told us about the project, but not the actual issue you are facing. *"I'd like to create a router outlet in my root component to display a "control strip" like interaction bar"* - and what issue are you having with this that we can help you with?

Comment: The problem lies with the approach. Is my ideal situation even possible? If so how can I adapt my component to serve an html file to that specific control strip router-outlet? Or if there are of course other best practices that I am completely overlooking.